# Xeon Phi: icc c++11 compatibility?

Tags: version, icc, intel-mic

I am considering getting a Xeon Phi card. My code is using many features from c++11 (with gcc 4.7 or clang 3.2) and I will run it natively on the Xeon Phi card.

What is the version of `icc` provided with the card, targeting Xeon Phi? I found [icc c++11 compatibility list](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler) and it seems that I need version 14. Do I get it with the card?

Related question: is there gcc/clang targeting Xeon Phi in development? I could not google anything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xeon Phi works with the latest shipping versions of the icc, which is version 13 at this time.
There is also a Xeon Phi targeted version of gcc which ships with the card.

Comment: According to Intel GCC cannot vectorize on Xeon Phi, which ruins its performance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614603/is-the-intel-xeon-phi-usable-without-a-costly-intel-compiler?rq=1

Comment: That is correct. Only ICC supports The vector instructions for Xeon Phi.

Comment: Using any compiler but ICC defeats the purpose of the Xeon Phi, unless Intel has an OpenCL driver for Xeon Phi that supports the vector instructions.