# Installing R `forecast` package on a Linux Cluster: compiler issues?

Tags: r, rcpp, forecasting, xeon-phi, icc

I am looking to test performance of `R`, more specifically some routines in the `forecast` package on an HPC cluster with Intel Xeon Phi co-processors.  The sysadmin has, I understand, built `R/3.2.5` from source following the instructions on Intel's website: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/build-r-301-with-intel-c-compiler-and-intel-mkl-on-linux

So `R` works, installation of packages including `devtools`, `data.table`, `dplyr`, `ggplot2`, `Rcpp`, `RcppArmadillo` can be carried out from within an `R` session using `install.packages` to install to a local user-specific library.  The reason I mention these packages is that they all require some form of compilation, hence I was required to include the line `module load intel/15.2.164` in my `.bashrc` file to get the compiler loaded.

However when I come to install the `forecast` package I have a failure.  There is a long stream of text output (see below) however in summary it appears as if something related to the compiler is failing:

```
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(115): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value + __y._M_value;
```

I'm afraid I understand very little about compiling software and administering/installing: these problems have never occurred for me previously on my Mac or the university Linux cluster.

```
> install.packages("forecast")
Installing package into '/gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/src/contrib/forecast_7.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 196896 bytes (192 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 192 KB

* installing *source* package 'forecast' ...
** package 'forecast' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
icpc -I/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/R/3.2.5/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/utilities/include -I"/gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include" -I"/gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fpic  -O2  -c calcBATS.cpp -o calcBATS.o
icpc -I/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/R/3.2.5/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/utilities/include -I"/gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include" -I"/gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fpic  -O2  -c calcTBATS.cpp -o calcTBATS.o
icpc -I/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/R/3.2.5/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/utilities/include -I"/gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include" -I"/gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fpic  -O2  -c etsTargetFunction.cpp -o etsTargetFunction.o
In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(69): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          _M_value = __z._M_value;
                         ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(77): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          _M_value = __z._M_value;
                         ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(115): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value + __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(115): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value + __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(120): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value - __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(120): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value - __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(125): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value * __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(125): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value * __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(130): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value / __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(130): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value / __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(134): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return -__x._M_value;
                      ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(141): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value == __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(141): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value == __y._M_value;
                                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(146): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value != __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(146): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value != __y._M_value;
                                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(150): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1157 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return ~__z._M_value;
                      ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(187): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value + __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(187): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value + __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(192): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value - __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(192): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value - __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(197): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value * __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(197): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value * __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(202): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value / __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(202): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value / __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(206): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return -__x._M_value;
                      ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(211): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value == __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(211): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value == __y._M_value;
                                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(216): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value != __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(216): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value != __y._M_value;
                                     ^

In file included from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from etsTargetFunction.h(3),
                 from etsTargetFunction.cpp(7):
/gpfs/stfc/local/apps/intel/intel_cs/2015.2.164/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/include/complex(220): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1302 of "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/complex") is inaccessible
          return ~__z._M_value;
                      ^

compilation aborted for etsTargetFunction.cpp (code 2)
make: *** [etsTargetFunction.o] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'forecast'
* removing '/gpfs/stfc/local/HCPhi012/mjw01/mjw93-mjw01/library/R/3.2.5/forecast'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmppswtIw/downloaded_packages'
Warning message:
In install.packages("forecast") :
  installation of package 'forecast' had non-zero exit status
```

It appears as if there is little documentation out there about `R` and the Xeon Phi co-processor and a single question on StackOverflow which remains unanswered:  [R Parallel Processing with Xeon Phi, minimal code changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635037/r-parallel-processing-with-xeon-phi-minimal-code-changes?noredirect=1#comment60804799_35635037)

I'd be very grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction here. Many thanks.

Comment: You probably want to switch compilers, at least for the [forecast](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) package.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel there is quite an array of compilers available in the list, several considerations come to mind: should I use the same compiler as R was built under, should I use an intel compiler, should I use a compiler related to the MIC? `forecast` is the most important package to my work, the purpose of this task is trying to optimise performance - how much does the choice of compiler matter in that respect?  Excuse my naivety here.   I will practise trial and error now.
OK, you are absolutely correct, the intel/14.0.4 module did the trick.  Many thanks Dirk

Comment: Keep it simple. Intel and gcc can mix, so build as much as you can under icc and only what fails (such as forecast) under gcc/g++.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have the same issue.  It seems RcppArmadillo gets the `#pragma warning (push)` and `#pragma warning (pop)` out of balance somehow.

By the time Intel's `complex` is processed you *must* have warning 308 disabled.

The easiest way is to add to R's Makeconf:

```
CXXFLAGS = -diag-disable 308
```

that solves the problem once and for all.

Answer (score 2):

Added the below line to my *~/.R/Makevars* and it solved the issue.

```
CXXFLAGS += -wd308
```