# R: compilation of multicool fails

Tags: r, compiler-errors, compilation, redhat

I want to install the `rugarch` library on a system running Red Hat 7.3 and R version 3.3.1. Unfortunately, I do not have admin rights on the machine.

The installation of `rugarch` fails due to a compilation errror of `multicool`.
Running `install.packages('multicool')` terminates with the error mesage:

```
compilation aborted for multicool.cpp (code 2)
make: *** [multicool.o] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘multicool’
```

And here is the full output:

```
> install.packages('multicool')
Installing package into ‘/pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/multicool_0.1-10.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 11387 bytes (11 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 11 KB

* installing *source* package ‘multicool’ ...
** package ‘multicool’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
icpc -I/opt/bwhpc/common/math/R/3.3.1-mkl-11.2.3-intel-15.0_O2_pragma_noopt/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O2  -std=c++11 -fp-model strict -openmp -xHost  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
icpc -I/opt/bwhpc/common/math/R/3.3.1-mkl-11.2.3-intel-15.0_O2_pragma_noopt/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O2  -std=c++11 -fp-model strict -openmp -xHost  -c compositions.cpp -o compositions.o
icpc -I/opt/bwhpc/common/math/R/3.3.1-mkl-11.2.3-intel-15.0_O2_pragma_noopt/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O2  -std=c++11 -fp-model strict -openmp -xHost  -c multicool.cpp -o multicool.o
In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(69): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          _M_value = __z._M_value;
                         ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(77): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          _M_value = __z._M_value;
                         ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(115): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value + __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(115): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value + __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(120): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value - __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(120): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value - __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(125): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value * __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(125): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value * __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(130): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value / __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(130): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value / __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(134): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return -__x._M_value;
                      ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(141): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value == __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(141): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value == __y._M_value;
                                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(146): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value != __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(146): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value != __y._M_value;
                                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(150): error #308: member "std::complex<float>::_M_value" (declared at line 1187 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return ~__z._M_value;
                      ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(187): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value + __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(187): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value + __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(192): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value - __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(192): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value - __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(197): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value * __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(197): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value * __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(202): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value / __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(202): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value / __y._M_value;
                                    ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(206): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return -__x._M_value;
                      ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(211): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value == __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(211): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value == __y._M_value;
                                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(216): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value != __y._M_value;
                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(216): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return __x._M_value != __y._M_value;
                                     ^

In file included from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h(64),
                 from /pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h(27),
                 from multicool.cpp(8):
/pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/intel/compxe.2015.3.187/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/complex(220): error #308: member "std::complex<double>::_M_value" (declared at line 1337 of "/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/complex") is inaccessible
          return ~__z._M_value;
                      ^

compilation aborted for multicool.cpp (code 2)
make: *** [multicool.o] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘multicool’
* removing ‘/pfs/data1/home/kn/kn_kn/kn_pop260093/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/multicool’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/scratch/RtmpQPqfE3/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("multicool") :
  installation of package ‘multicool’ had non-zero exit status
```

Is there any way to install the library?

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question? I am using R on a university cluster, and have been running into this problem every time they upgrade their software. It is very relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding

```
CXXFLAGS = -diag-disable 308
```

to  `~/.R/Makevars` solved my issue (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722505/installing-r-forecast-package-on-a-linux-cluster-compiler-issues)).

Comment: Indeed it helps! If this file does not exist, one should create it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by BayerSe no longer works in 2020 because the compiler is explicitly using the C++11 standard. Add

```
CXXFLAGS = -diag-disable 308
CXX11FLAGS = -diag-disable 308
```

to `~/.R/Makevars`. Discussion [here](https://github.com/rstudio/httpuv/issues/120).